# How to make div background image inside another div to responsive?

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I've been struggling with this issue for a while although tried from many topics in StackOverflow, and just wondered if anyone has any advice!

I'm using Bootstrap 3, basically I want to place images inside the container `<div>`, that will resize with the browser window, the content still staying inside it. So how can I make it responsive? Thank you in advance!

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/thehung1724/full/emZXQK)**

**HTML**

```
<div id="special-dishes-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="special-dishes">
        </div>    <!-- end special-dishes -->
    </div>    <!-- end container -->
</div>    <!-- end special-dishes-section -->
```

**CSS**

```
#special-dishes-section{
    background: url('../images/special-dishes-bg.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    min-height: 560px;
    padding: 71px 0 65px 0;
    position: relative;
}

.special-dishes{
    background: url('../images/wooden-bg.png') no-repeat center center;
    min-height: 424px;
}
```

Comment: Are the images you want to place in <img> tags or css background-images?

Answer (score 0):

```
box-sizing: border-box;
```

This property help you when it needs to be responsive.
See this link for more information:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp

Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Try `background-size: cover;` or `background-size: contain;`.

Comment: You might just want to get a little more detailed at this answer... Give some examples on why does it solve the OP's question...

Comment: @LcSalazar, should it be something like this? [http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEZwNW](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/qEZwNW)

Comment: Please see my [**live example**](http://thehung.esy.es/Mozzarella/). When resize brower, the background too small for the inside content, I mean want to height expand auto.